# Extract duplicated method which is used in many packages

Tags: java, refactoring, code-duplication

I have a method:

```
    private Replace ReplaceType(final ReplaceTypeDao replaceTypeDao, final Long key) {
        final Optional<ReplaceType> replaceTypeEntry = replaceTypeDao.findById(key, true);

        if (!replaceTypeEntry.isPresent()) {
            throw new TypeIsMissing(key);
        }
        return replaceTypeEntry.get();
    }
```

which is exactly the same in other classes but from different packages. I could create class (but in which package?) with method `replaceTypeProcess`, then call new class constructor and `newClassInstance.replaceTypeProcess()` but I don't like this solution. How to do it in best manner?

Comment: You could make it a static method of the `Replace` class? That way you can be assured that the types are correctly referenced/imported and you would not need to worry about making new instances of the object before calling the method (Depending on where `TypeIsMissing` comes from you might have to re-think your error/throw).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a package `utility` And put some common classes in it.

You can also look [this link on how to remove duplicate method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107458/how-to-remove-duplicate-code-in-general).

And as you mentionned it you can make a static method. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/when-to-use-static-methods) is a very nice post about the use of static methods.

Comment: I thought about Util class but good practice is to have static method there. Is there a way without static?

Comment: I will edit my post with a nice post on when you should or not use static method. In your case if you don't want to use static and don't want to add a utility package I don't really know what you can do.